# SFINAE and decay don't work together. Why?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I'm just learning metaprogramming in C++. I want to make auto detector of opengl type id based on passed type. My code passes `decltype(array)` which becomes `float*`. If I use `GLType<float>::type` it works fine, but `GLType<float*>::type` fails with "unknown member type" error. I thought `std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, float>>` will evaluate to `true_type` on any `float*, float[], const float, etc..` as stated [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay)

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct GLType {};

template <typename T>
struct GLType<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, float>>> {
    const static constexpr int type = GL_FLOAT;
};

template <typename T>
struct GLType<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, double>>> {
    const static constexpr int type = GL_DOUBLE;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::decay_t` does not remove the pointer from a type. If you want to do that, you need to use [`std::remove_pointer_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer), like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct GLType<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::remove_pointer_t<std::decay_t<T>>, float>>> {
                                             //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  add this   
 const static constexpr int type = GL_FLOAT;
};
```

and similarly for the other template.

Comment: Yes, `decay_t` will make `float[]` be the same as `float*` for example, but doesn't remove the pointer.